# Install ubuntu in LenovoG500s

Tags: windows-8, lenovo

I have a laptop branded lenovo G500s with windows 8 pre installed.I need to install Ubuntu as a secondary operating system in my laptop without removing my current Operating System.
Is it possible?

I have run  the installation CD and which says no operating system found in my system.The ubuntu not detecting my current operating system.
If i proceed with the next steps,anything happen to my current OS?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows 8 (64-bit) System (UEFI Supported)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported)

Answer (score 2):

if you are afraid to break anything and just want to try it do the following:

1. -mount ubuntu image on windows with daemon tools
2. -from there run wubi.exe it will make you a ubuntu installation on your disk.

reboot and voila you have side by side.

Comment: is wubi work with windows 8?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gZqsXAoLBDI yes it will =)